# Add tag to bug when pull request finishes succesfully Devops

Tags: build, azure-devops, devops, pull-request

Anybody knows if it is possible to add a predefined tag to all bug work item types linked to a pull request, when the pull request is completed in devops?

Answer (score 1):

No, by default. As workaround, if you have CI build, you can add a custom step with rest api (with PowerShell or something else):

1. Get last commit detail information: [Commits - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Then you can find work items the workItems field.
2. Update each work item: [Work Items - Update (Add a tag)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-tag)

Comment: Thanks Shamira. Yes, I do have build and also thought about the way you are talking about but, i was specting something faster to build, and also the project my team is developing is quite big, and only taking into account  the bunch of tests we are executing takes a while... so I don't want to penalize builds because some management issue. Thanks Anyway. +1